# How to put a text label *before* an equation?

Tags: equations

currently I have an optimization problem defined in {equation} environment:

[image]

I want to add a label (P) before equation (6).

Currently, I had to use the first line "Optimization problem (P)" as a workaround.

Ideally, I'd like it to look like this: 

[image]

I tried to use {IEEEeqnarray}, but it didn't work well. Also tried to google, but couldn't find an answer.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: In case you don't need the label `(6)`, you could use the command `\tag{(P)}` together with `\label` for your equation. It will change the `(6)` by `(P)`, and each time you call the equation it compiler put a `(P)`. **Note:** the package `amsmath` needs to be loaded.

Comment: @Dox Thanks - I tried to use \tag{P}, but ideally, I still want the label (6) to be there because I need to cross-reference it elsewhere in the paper with (6), not with (P).

Comment: I have a feeling that you're going to seriously confuse your reader by this `(P)` and `(6)` schizophreny, but do as you wish :)

Comment: @tohecz Actually...(P) refers to the entire optimization problem including (6) and a bunch of other constraints (7)(8)..., where (6) is only the objective equation of (P). That's how I'll cross-reference them in the context. Do you think this is not a good idea? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the method described in [Formula label outside of formula](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117552/formula-label-outside-of-formula/117555#117555)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent text
\begin{flalign}
\text{(P)}&&\min_{x_{ij},\delta_i} \sum_{i=1}^m (P_i^{svr} + P_i^{cool})&&\phantom{\text{(P)}}
\end{flalign}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

*As daleif points out in the comments, the textual superscripts like "svr" and "cool" should be in upright, not italic, text.  I left them italic, mimicking the OP's original effort, since they had nothing to do with placing the label on the left.  More properly, one should use `\mathrm{}` or one of the several other ways to force those superscripts upright.*

And here is another way to achieve the leftward label, using my `stackengine` package instead of `amsmath` (the only quirk is the `\rule` that I added because the vertical space above the equation was otherwise too short).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\noindent text
\begin{equation}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\stackon[0pt]{$\displaystyle\min_{x_{ij},\delta_i} \sum_{i=1}^m (P_i^{svr} + P_i^{cool})
$}{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{(P)}\rule{0ex}{5.5ex}}
\end{equation}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

One flexibility of this approach is that you could make the `\makebox` of width, for example, `[.9\textwidth]` which would provide for a constant indent of the label with respect to the left margin.

Finally, If one didn't need the label left-aligned, but merely offset to the left (let's say a fixed amount), a third approach could use `\llap{(P)\hspace{1in}}` at the beginning of the equation in the `equation` environment.

Comment: Better than my suggestion! Thank you for the trick!

Comment: Remember to put the named indices in upright font

Comment: @daleif Are you referring to "svr" and "cool"?  I mimicked the OP's code, but I agree that these should be upright.

Comment: Yes, those indices, basically just to let others coming by know, that that is what they should remember to do

Comment: @daleif I added some parenthetical remarks admonishing the user to do what I say, not what I do.  Thanks for the tip.