# Tabbing/horizontal placement with labeled equations

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations

I have a string of equations, each with a label that I would like to format nicely. I want the equation labels to be at the same horizontal position and the start of the equation to be at the same horizontal location. Additionally, I want each equation to have a label.

There seem to be a large number of ways this could be done, but I can't get anything to work correctly. A tabbing seems to not work with equations. Also tried putting the equation in a \vbox with tabbing, but that kills the formatting.

Example:

```
      Label:           Equation
      Longer label:    Equation
      Lab:             Equation
```

What I'm working with

```
%+++++++++++
\begin{equation}
\label{e:failuniaxlocal}
Uniaxial Local Buckling: MOS=\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma}-1
\end{equation}
%+++++++++++


%+++++++++++
\begin{equation}
\label{e:failuniaxlocal}
Uniaxial Local Buckling:
\end{equation}
%+++++++++++

%+++++++++++
\begin{equation}
\label{e:failshearlocal}
Shear Local Buckling:
\end{equation}
%+++++++++++

%+++++++++++
\begin{equation}
\label{e:failinterlocal}
Uniaxial-Shear Interaction:
\end{equation}
%+++++++++++

%+++++++++++
\begin{equation}
\label{e:failstffbck}
Stiffener buckling: MOS=\frac{pi^2 H_{22}}{P L^2}-1
\end{equation}
%+++++++++++

enter code here
```

Comment: Do you want equations to be numbered?

Comment: If you want them numbered then this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159800/how-to-put-a-text-label-before-an-equation/159803#159803 can help.  And since you say you want labels, I think it is a pretty good assumption that you want them numbered (or else, what will you `\ref`?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're going to spread out the content with some paragraphs between them, then you could surely use a construction like the one below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}%
\newcommand{\labeleqn}[3][150pt]{%
  \makebox[0pt]{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{#2}}% Set label
  \makebox[0pt]{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\hspace*{#1}$\displaystyle#3$}}}% Set equation

\begin{document}

%+++++++++++
\begin{equation}
\labeleqn{Uniaxial Local Buckling:}{MOS = \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma} - 1}
\label{e:failuniaxlocal}
\end{equation}
%+++++++++++

%+++++++++++
\begin{equation}
\labeleqn{Shear Local Buckling:}{f(x)=ax^2 + bx + c}
\label{e:failshearlocal}
\end{equation}
%+++++++++++

%+++++++++++
\begin{equation}
\labeleqn{Uniaxial-Shear Interaction:}{e = mc^2}
\label{e:failinterlocal}
\end{equation}
%+++++++++++

%+++++++++++
\begin{equation}
\labeleqn{Stiffener buckling:}{MOS=\frac{\pi^2 H_{22}}{P L^2} - 1}
\label{e:failstffbck}
\end{equation}
%+++++++++++

\end{document}
```

`\labeleqn[<width>]{<label>}{<eqn>}` sets `<eqn>` starting `<width>` (default is `150pt`) from the left margin while also adding `<label>` flush with the left margin.

Alternatively one can use [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align` environment to align the equations at the `=`.

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I did try amsmath align, but was having trouble getting it to work with the equation numbering.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution using `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
&\text{Uniaxial Local Buckling:}     &\qquad &MOS=\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma}-1   \label{e:failuniaxlocal}\\
&\text{Shear Local Buckling:}        &       &MOS=\frac{1}{2}                 \label{e:failshearlocal}\\
&\text{Uniaxial-Shear Interaction:}  &       &MOS=\frac{1}{4}                 \label{e:failinterlocal}\\
&\text{Stiffener buckling:}          &       &MOS=\frac{pi^2 H_{22}}{P L^2}-1 \label{e:failstffbck}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I attempted this, but it must have conflicted with other settings in my document. The equation numbers don't show up in my document.

Comment: @August you have probably used `alignat*` (starred version) instead of `alignat`