# how to put parent counter of numcases before equation and child counter after equation

Tags: math-mode, cases

I want to make a `subnumcases`-like environment, named `mynumcases`, like this

[image]

I will explain what I want and what I have tried.

- what I want:

1. equations in `mynumcases` have a parent counter which is same as `equation`
2. I want to put this parent counter before the big brace, and has a fixed length away from left margin (I don't know what the left line's name), this length doesn't need to set as an argument.

[image]

3. `\Roman` parent counter and `\alph` child counter
4. (option) I can make my own tag at the position of the parent counter

- what I have tried

  1. I refered this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343157/180617
  2. I found I can't use this method in my demand.
  3. I tried to use `empheq` package's `[left=...]` argument.

Here is my code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, environ}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\def\Rom{\@Roman}

\NewEnviron{mynumcases}[2][\@nil]{%
\def\tmp@ne{#1}
\refstepcounter{equation}
\edef\oldeqnum{\theequation}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{equation}}
\begin{empheq}[left={\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[.3\linewidth][l]{\ifx\tmp@ne\@nnil (\Rom{\oldeqnum}) \else #1 \fi}}#2\empheqlbrace}]{align}
  \BODY
\end{empheq}
\setcounter{equation}{\oldeqnum}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

first equation
\begin{equation}
  1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}

first mynumcases

\begin{mynumcases}{}
  & 1 + 1 = 2\\
  & 1 = 1
\end{mynumcases}

another equation

\begin{equation}
  test
\end{equation}

second mynumcases

\begin{mynumcases}{f(x)=}
  & 1+1+1+1+1 & \text{if } hello\\
  & 1 + 1 & \text{if } hello\\
  & 1 & \text{if } hello\\
  & 1
\end{mynumcases}

third mynumcases

\begin{mynumcases}[my words]{f(x)=}
  & 1+1+1+1+1\\
  & 1 + 1\\
  & 1
\end{mynumcases}
\end{document}
```

and the whole output

[image]

And we can notice that

1. the parent counter has the fixed length away from the equation, not left margin
2. I have to put `&` before every line to make it align left
3. `if hello` is far away from `1+1..`

How can I reach my demand? Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the process I followed to achieve the requested solution:

1. Store the coordinate of the left margin using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) and [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module. We place a "label" `lm` at the start of the first page in the lower left corner of the text block. We'll use this x-coordinate in a calculation when setting any labels for `mynumcases`.
2. Insert the appropriate equation label (either the optional argument or the actual equation number in `\Roman`) via `\inserteqnum`, by...
3. ...inserting an appropriately-sized box to the left of `empheq` based on the location of the argument passed to `empheq`. The calculations use an equation-specific x-coordinate marker (also thanks to `zref`'s `savepos` module), the aforementioned `l`eft `m`argin x-coordinate and a predefined `\empheqnumindent` length that sets it off from the left margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,zref-savepos}
\usepackage{empheq,eso-pic}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtTextLowerLeft{\zsaveposx{lm}}}% Save left margin x-coordinate

\newlength{\empheqnumindent}
\setlength{\empheqnumindent}{25pt}
\newcounter{oldeqnum}
\newcommand{\inserteqnum}{%
  \zsaveposx{empheq-\theRequation}% Store position of LHS of empheq
  \makebox[0pt][r]{% Right-aligned 0pt-width box (pushes empheq number to the left)
    \makebox[\dimexpr\zposx{empheq-\theRequation}sp-\zposx{lm}sp-\empheqnumindent][l]{% Position equation number
      \theRequation% Set equation number
    }}%
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mynumcases}{o m}{%
  \IfValueF{#1}{\refstepcounter{equation}}% Only step equation counter if no optional argument
  % Store equation number (or optional argument)
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\gdef\noexpand\theRequation{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}
      {#1}
      {(\Roman{equation})}}}\x% Store equation number
  \setcounter{oldeqnum}{\value{equation}}% Store value of equation counter
  \setcounter{equation}{0}% Reset equation counter
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{equation}}% Update equation counter representation
  \empheq[left={\inserteqnum#2\empheqlbrace}]{align}
}{
  \endempheq
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{oldeqnum}}% Restore equation counter
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

first equation
\begin{equation}
  1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}

first mynumcases
\begin{mynumcases}{}
  & 1 + 1 = 2\\
  & 1 = 1
\end{mynumcases}
another equation
\begin{equation}
  test
\end{equation}

second mynumcases
\begin{mynumcases}{f(x)=}
  & 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 && \text{if } x   \\
  & 1 + 1             && \text{if } yy  \\
  & 1                 && \text{if } zzz \\
  & 1
\end{mynumcases}

third mynumcases
\begin{mynumcases}[my words]{f(x)=}
  & 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 \\
  & 1 + 1             \\
  & 1
\end{mynumcases}

\end{document}
```

Since this approach uses (La)TeX's `\label`-`\ref`-like system, any change in the page dimensions (technically, the left margin on the first page) or the `mynumcases` width would require an additional compilation.

This approach can be adapted for `twoside` more, or arbitrary page layouts. The approach would be to insert an page-specific `l`eft `m`argin marker rather than just one at the start of the document.